# Trying to have a select like option button of IonicV2 in my IonicV1 app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there a possibility of getting select and option mentioned in the Ionic Version 2 in the link : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/ to be integrated in my Ionic V1 app?